# Sitecore WFFM Checkbox Id

Tags: .net, sitecore

I am trying to grab the id on the input field for a checkbox generated by WFFM. Here is a snippet of the resulting html:

```
<label>
<input id="wffm9545cec6a2354c0a88f8bc4a5b470cbd_Sections_0__Fields_9__Value" 
    name="wffm9545cec6a2354c0a88f8bc4a5b470cbd.Sections[0].Fields[9].Value" 
    type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="wffm9545cec6a2354c0a88f8bc4a5b470cbd.Sections[0].Fields[9].Value" 
    type="hidden" value="false">I agree ...**
```

My reason for doing this is because my code was dinged for not being ADA Screen Reader friendly. The format I need to get it in is like this:

```
<input id="unique-id-1" ...>
<label for="unique-id-1" type="checkbox" ...>Label text</label>
```

My solution is to edit the default cshtml file for the checkbox (or maybe create a custom field) with the suggested formatting. I am open to suggestions to a better solution as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure about ADA compliance, but just be mindful and test that changing the field id cos not break validation and the submission of the form data.

Comment: Thanks @jammykam. Great blog by the way. Saved my butt last sprint :)